# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'parameter_name' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using two views 'EmployeeList' and 'Edit' respectively. From the view EmployeeList, i make call to a method called 'Edit' which returns the 'Edit' view in controller named 'Employee'. there is a submit button in 'Edit' view which calls Edit_Employee method in the 'Employee' controller. Respective views are given below.

```
EmployeeList.cshtml
  <tbody>
        @{
            if (Model.Emp_List != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Emp_List)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.row_number</td>
                    <td style="display:none">@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Designation</td>
                    <td>@item.Department</td>
                    <td>@item.Phone</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit", "Employee", new { id = item.Id,flag=1},null)

                    </td>
                </tr>
                    }
                }
            }

    </tbody>
```

```
Edit.cshtml
<h2>Edit Employee</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Emp_List)
    {
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputname">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@item.Name" name="Name" placeholder="name" id="inputname">              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputDesignation">Designation</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@item.Designation" name="Designation" placeholder="designation" id="inputDesignation">
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit " formaction="Edit_Employee" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
}
```

Employee controller methods given

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id, int flag)
        {
            IList<Employee> emp_editlist = new List<Employee>();
            EmployeeList e = new EmployeeList();
            try
            {
                if (Employeedetailssession.Current.Session["emplist"] != null)
                {
                    emp_editlist = this.GetSession("emplist");
                    emp_editlist = emp_editlist.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();
                }
                e.Emp_List = emp_editlist;
                e.Return_Param = 0;
            } 
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            if (flag == 1)
                return View("Edit", e);
            else
                return View("Details", e);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit_Employee(EmployeeList emp)
        {
            EmployeeList empobj = new EmployeeList();
            try
            {                             
                string message = string.Empty;
                HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

                hc.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
                var EditRec = hc.PostAsJsonAsync<EmployeeList>("EmployeeApi", emp);
                EditRec.Wait();
                var updatedata = EditRec.Result;
                if (updatedata.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    empobj = updatedata.Content.ReadAsAsync<EmployeeList>().Result;
                }
                    else
                {
                    empobj.Emp_List = null;
                    empobj.Return_Param = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout) { }
                else throw;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Edit",empobj);
        }
```

The issue is, when I call the Edit method from EmployeeList view , details are successfully loaded. but after making few changes and click Submit button, it wont hit Edit_Employee method instead showing error as

> 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, Int32)' in 'Vidly.Controllers.EmployeeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.'

It seems on button click also it hits 'Edit' method.. Why it doesnt hit the right method?
I want to navigate to Edit_Employee method on submit click. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing `formaction` from submit and use `Html.BeginForm("Edit_Employee", "Employee", FormMethod.Post)`

Comment: Unrelated, but important: Don't swallow exceptions and don't create new `HttpClient` instances. Prefer to use `async`/`await` and not `Wait()`/or `.Result`